# Добавление и удаление для ObservableCollection из другого класса

Tags: c#, wpf

Я создал коллекции ObservableCollection, который работает с привязками и т. д. Теперь у меня проблема, я не могу получить к нему доступ из других классов. Пробовал большинство вещей, но, вероятно, не хватает некоторых очевидных вещей.

```
public MyFavorites()
{
    ObservableServers = new ObservableCollection<Server>();
}

private ObservableCollection<Server> _myListOfServersObjects;
public ObservableCollection<Server> ObservableServers
{
    get => _myListOfServersObjects;
    set
    {
        if (_myListOfServersObjects != value)
        {
            _myListOfServersObjects = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ObservableServers");
        }
    }
}
```

Полный код: https://pastebin.com/KLFHwhKg

Как я пытался добавить элемент: https://pastebin.com/p7dBDcXq

Comment: А что мешает просто сделать `MyFavorites myFavorites = new MyFavorites();` и дальше просто `myFavorites.ObservableServers.Add(...);`? Не понимаю, для чего вы тут синглтон пытаетесь реализовать... P.S. Для `ObservableCollection` реализации `INotifyPropertyChanged` избыточна.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ если бы было всё так просто, я наверное сюда вопрос бы не задал.

Comment: Ну так наверно стоит уточнить что и как? Я лично в вашем коде не вижу не каких проблем с инициализацией класса и затем его использования в нужных объектах. В данном варианте вопроса ответ прост: `инициализируйте класс и работайте с коллекцией внутри (как я показал выше)`. Хотите другой ответ - стоит тогда переформулировать вопрос так, что бы он не казался столь банальным и бессмысленным.